# A mysterious exception here: XamlParseException

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamlparseexception

Here is my code:

```
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    List<Cliente> CContent;
    string mainPath = @"D:\70-536\Clientes.dat";

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Do();
    }

    private void Do()
    {

        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(mainPath);
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            CContent = ReturnListOfPersistentFile<Cliente>(mainPath);
        }
        else
        {
            CContent = new List<Cliente>();
        }
    }

    public List<T> ReturnListOfPersistentFile<T> (string Filename)
    {
        SoapFormatter sf = new SoapFormatter();

        using (Stream fStream = new FileStream(Filename,FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read,FileShare.None))
        {
            List<T> list = new List<T>();
            list = (List<T>)sf.Deserialize(fStream);

            return list;
        }

    }
```

This is the stacktrace of my innerexception:

> en System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(Exception e)    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String arg)    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowUnclosedElements()    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseAttributes()    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElement()    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseDocumentContent()    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Read()    en
>   System.Xml.XmlTextReader.Read()    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.ParseXml()
>   en System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapParser.Run()    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler
>   handler, ISerParser serParser)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler)    en
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap.SoapFormatter.Deserialize(Stream
>   serializationStream)    en
>   Solution1.MainWindow.ReturnListOfPersistentFile[T](String Filename) en
>   c:\users\u201114160\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Solution1\Solution1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:línea 99    en
>   Solution1.MainWindow.Do() en c:\users\u201114160\documents\visual
>   studio 2010\Projects\Solution1\Solution1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:línea 45
>   en Solution1.MainWindow..ctor() en
>   c:\users\u201114160\documents\visual studio
>   2010\Projects\Solution1\Solution1\MainWindow.xaml.cs:línea 36

It drives me crazy, some ideas? This exception was throwed because "ReturnListOfPersistentFile" generic method, but WHY?

Thanks in advance.

**ANSWER:**
I was trying to serialize a generic list with SOAP formatter, but SOAP formatter doesn't support generic lists.

I ran into this thread on [forums.microsoft.com.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/ee4a7a63-290e-432f-bd45-44f4cb7a3467/) Let me quote what microsoft employee said:

> We have decided not to invest in any significant new feature work for the SoapFormatter in Whidbey

Thanks everyone.

Comment: ... because you got a corrupted file?

Comment: Not exacly, because SOAP serialization doesn't support generic lists.:(

Comment: Sorry men, I looked around and I don't find any question similar to mine. Anyway I had to explain how I fix it. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your stacktrace, I notice the method ThrowUnclosedElements. This makes me think that you got a corrupted or ill-formated file.

As yourself have pointed out, SOAP serialization doesn't support generic lists. As I understand, this means that you tried to serialize a List and as result you got a file that cannot be deserialized. This have been discussed before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657654/net-remoting-problems-with-listt), and also [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/ee4a7a63-290e-432f-bd45-44f4cb7a3467/) (your own cite) among other places.

A solution may be to use a non-generic, old fashion, forgotten [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist). Of course you got to access the items and cast them to the appropriate type, this can be done with a wrapper class.

An alternative is to serialize object per object, instead of serializing the list.

Comment: I googled up for generic list and SOAP serialization, and I found that site. I appreciate the details of that response.